# Where is redeem code for public link for TestFlight?

Tags: ios, testflight, testflight-public-link

Sent public URL to a user, and he reported TestFlight does not show the app, but asked for a redeem code? Where can I or he find this code?

Comment: You have shared the public link, how it would show up in TestFlight?
Just open the public link and follow instructions.

Comment: That doesn't work; that's what the OP is reporting. I'm having the same problem. The prospective testers are getting different and erroneous results. Two were shown a dialog saying that the app is "invalid" (despite another external tester using the exact same build), and another got this demand for an "invitation code." I tried adding one guy's Apple ID directly, but when he accepted THAT invitation, it said he'd already accepted it and to ask me for a new one. Guess what: You CAN'T send a new one, because AppStoreConnect shows he accepted & doesn't offer to let you re-send. Brilliant, Apple.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The redeem code is sent by mail when you add an external or internal new tester in TestFlight.

When you open your app in App Store Connect, go to "My Apps" and select your app. Then go to the "TestFlight" section, complete the "Information" section, and then add external testers as needed and the build to test.

After this Apple sends emails to all testers with the invitation.

A good tutorial on TestFlight can be found on [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5352-testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing).

Comment: You need to click on the link inside the mail to get to the Redeem code. It's not in the text, at least it wasn't for me.

Comment: the comment below is a better answer than this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61337238/3163882

Answer (score 17):

[tl;dr user is doing it wrong + Apple designed this flow poorly.]

Presumably what is happening is some users who haven't previously installed TestFlight (or who opened the link in an app other than Safari, which won't automatically open TestFlight for them) are clicking on the public link, which if opened on an iOS device shows: "Step 1 Get TestFlight".

[image: screenshot of testflight sign up]

(notice that on many devices some portion of "Step 2" will be covered up, such as the critical "Start Testing" button in the screenshot above.)

And then instead of returning to the webpage after installing TestFlight and scrolling down and clicking the "Start Testing" button under "Step 2 Join the Beta", some users are mistakenly staying in the TestFlight app and either tapping the "Redeem" button as it is the only interactable element on the mostly empty default TestFlight screen or reading the subtitle that says to "contact the developer for an invitation code."

[image: screenshot of empty TestFlight]
(Note the big title text would be confusing to users who thought this was how they start testing and they would naturally think at this point something has gone wrong.)

Unfortunately this is a natural consequence of the way this workflow is designed, and I don't see a simple way around it besides educating your users. 
Certainly one workaround is to invite the user via email, so they will get a code they can enter into the "Redeem" alert text field, but this should not be necessary.

It may seem obvious to technically-savvy people, but one can clearly see some people not understanding that they need to switch back and forth like that. Until this design flaw is fixed, a certain percentage will make this mistake. I suggest [sending Apple some feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) about this.

Comment: My emails inviting me do not contain a redeem code. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: If you tap the link in the email on any kind of device without TestFlight installed it will open a webpage with 3 steps, instructing you to get TestFlight, open it, and enter a redemption code. Might also

Comment: [Here's an edited screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/AO9Egbs.png)

Comment: You have no idea how long I have been looking for a way to get the redemption codes. I kept opening on iOS devices and not seeing it. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 15):

This issue is happening to me also. Some customers are saying they are asked to enter the redeem code while using the public link for downloading the app from TestFlight, so they are unable to download the app.

Workaround was to add the user's email id to the test group so it will send email invites with redeem code.

But I still do not understand why the public URL for downloading the app is asking for a redeem code? And what will be the redeem code for people using the public link? Another interesting thing is it's happening only to some users.

Comment: Still happening in 2020, also just for some users.

Comment: It’s happening to a link I generated today. For different users using the same link, some reported that nothing showed up in test flight

Comment: Still happening, and somehow, the invited users didn't receive an invitation from TestFlight, so they are stuck with the prompt for the redeem code.
@Lee: How did you trigger resending the invites? How did you add the user's email id to the test group, other than assigning them individually? (That process does not send another invite).

Comment: Still happening in late 2021.

Comment: Still happening in 2022. TestFlight does not say anything about the redeem code in their TestFlight documentation: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: Still happening summer 2022. I have a user trying on different devices/accounts where the public link just opens up TestFlight and the prompt to accept or install isn't coming up. But there is a "Redeem" button on the top right. So next logical step is add them as an external tester so an email is sent out.

Comment: Still happening in 2024, I'm adding the user manually to the TestFlight testers external group, but this seems like it should be an unnecessary step...

Answer (score 4):

My rep is too low to comment, but something you can also do is ask your testers to do a "long press" on the link. This will allow them to open the link in either Safari or TestFlight. Opening in TestFlight will sometimes resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

For public links, when you click the link, it'll open a page with two steps to follow. The first step is to download the TestFlight app. The second step is to install your app. After you install TestFlight, go back to the link and press the install button on the second step. There is no need to redeem codes for public links.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works in March 2024

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with the same issue here.
I found a couple of things.

If you're trying to renew a previously added a user, go to the same version you initially issued the code on. If you don't see reissue as an option, try deleting / then add new external tester. If you try to reissue the redeem code on a different (newer?) TestFlight version that option is unavailable. First time-adds should also show the reissue button after you send the first invite.

TestFlight "redeem" button is the top of the left panel.

If you are working on an app-managed computer. You need to have rights to run TestFlight and access the AppleStore.

I have one last hurtle and I think it's a security feature of the managing application (JAMF ?).

Answer (score 0):

alternately, your build could be ‘approved’, but you’ve not yet ‘notify’ testers. So you’ve not made the build available. This wording can throw you off, since ‘notify’ sounds like an email thing, unrelated to link invitations.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user's phone is running the correct iOS version. I've just had this happen with an app testflighting on iOS 17 but they were still on iOS 16 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -2):

It typically happens when the user is not registered to the App Store and/or iTunes with the given email address. In my case it turned out that my tester gave me his iCloud email which was why he experienced the same issue.

Comment: There is no given email address in this case, as users are installing via a public link. And if you are registering via an email entered into TestFlight manually, the email does not need to be registered with the App Store or iTunes. It just needs to be a valid email address to receive the invite.